# Django: Negative indexing and 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: django, list, python-3.x

Alright, so I want to find a list of numbers not present in the database with as maximum the highest number. And I have this code:

```
numbers_objects = Numbers.objects.all().filter(series=1).order_by('number')
numbers_all = number_objects.values_list('number', flat=True).order_by('number')
numbers_missing = [n for n in range(67,numbers_all[-1]) if n not in numbers_all]
```

This yields error `Negative indexing not allowed`. Alright, so I look in the documentation and tried:

```
numbers_missing = [n for n in range(67,numbers_all[number_all.count()-1]) if n not in numbers_all]
```

This yields error `'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Could anyone tell me how Django thinks we should access the last element in a list if both the pythonic way and the documented way do not work?

Comment: `numbers_all[number_all.count()-1]` is not an integer, I'd say. :-)

Comment: What is the type of `number` in model `Numbers'?

Comment: @both above comments... Both are right.. `numbers_all(numbers_all.count()-1` is a string. I forgot that my numbers_list also includes special cases, for example: [1,2,4,6,10,'t','s']. Is there a way to find the last integer in this list?

Comment: Already figured it out by using a list comprehension to create a new list with only integers by using: `actual_numbers = [e for e in numbers_all if isinstance(e, int)]`